# Is it possible to change image of google.maps.GroundOverlay using javascript?

Tags: image, google-maps-api-3, overlay

I am using Google Maps for a weather information display web.

I want to show the cloud condition for past seven days.

I am using overlays to display clouds on my web.

Now my question is can we change image of **google.maps.GroundOverlay** using javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is not possible to change the image of a GroundOverlay.  The image is set in the constructor and there is currently no setter documented to change it.

What you could try is to create two GroundOverlays with the same coordinates but pass the constructor `map:null` on one of them so it doesn't show on your map.  Then, when you want to replace the image, call `setMap(null)` on the overlay that is showing--that will hide it--and then call `setMap(map)` (assuming you set your map to a variable named `map`) on the overlay that you want to show.

Answer (score 3):

There's currently no way to change GroundOverlay's image via maps API. Instead, create new GroundOverlay with the same bounds for the new image. And remove the original GroundOverlay.

Answer (score 3):

This has changed from 2011.

In Google Maps API V3, [GroundOverlay class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#GroundOverlay) extends [MVCObject](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MVCObject) which has getters and setters.

So you can indeed change image of ground overlay with `overlay.set("url", newImage)`. Similarly, you can change overlays bounds with `overlay.set("bounds",bounds)`.

After changing overlay properties, you have to reassign the map object to it with `overlay.setMap(map)`.